# Python Tkinter Text Widget: Setting font won't work when using a variable

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I have a `Text` widget from `tkinter` for which I am trying to change the font. I have found out how to do this but one of the ways doesn't seem to work and I was wondering if there is a reason why.

When I set the font inline it works fine: `self.text.configure(font=("Segoe UI", 10))`

but when I try to use a variable it doesn't seem to keep the font size but it changes the family:

```
self.text_font = Font(family="Segoe UI", size=10)
self.text.configure(font=self.text_font)
```

So why do I get different results when using an outer variable and why does it only keep the font family?

Comment: I know this won't help too much but either way works fine for me.

Comment: @bernie I think I may have found a reason why. I think that it may because the `self.text_font` is a `tkinter.font` object which for whatever reason may be causing the problem. Because when I did `self.text_font = ("Segoe UI", 8)` and `self.text.configure(text=self.text_font)` it worked perfectly fine. So my only thought is using the `tkinter.font` object is what is causing the problem

Comment: That could explain it... FYI I was using a variable called `text_font` and not `self.text_font`...

Comment: That font object should work. You are probably changing size somewhere else. Can you provide [MCVE]?

Comment: The code in your question is correct. The problem must be in some other code somewhere. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Lafexlos I'm not sure where, but you must be correct in that I must be changing the size somewhere else because when I went to create the MCVE the problem did not occur. I'm going to further review the code and see where the problem may be